# ¿Qué edades comprende la definición de "adolescencia"? ¿Cómo y por qué ha evolucionado con el tiempo?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, historia, tiempo

Leyendo [*12 palabras que cambiaron completamente de significado*](https://lacabezallena.com/lengua/diccionario-estrafalario/) me encuentro con numerosos casos interesantes. Hoy me centro en *adolescencia*:

> > ADOLESCENCIA. s. f. La edad desde catorce hasta veinte y cinco años. *Adolescentia*. SOLIS Hist. de Nuev. Esp. lib. 3. cap. 14. Habia maestros de niñez, adolescencia, y juventud.
>
> En el diccionario de 1770 aparece la palabra adolescencia con un significado muy similar al actual, pero nos sorprende su duración: ¡hasta los 25 años!

Efectivamente, mirando en el [Mapa de diccionarios](http://web.frl.es/ntllet/) observamos cómo la definición ha ido variando con el tiempo:

> **1780** y **1817**. s. f. La edad desde catorce hasta veinte y cinco años. *Adolescentia*.
>
> **1884** y **1925**. f. Edad que sucede á la infancia y que transcurre desde que a perocen [aparecen] los primeros indicios de la pubertad hasta el completo desarrollo del cuerpo.
>
> **1992** u **2001**. f. Edad que sucede a la niñez y que transcurre desde la pubertad hasta el completo desarrollo del organismo.

Como en algunos casos se habla de ***pubertad***, analicemos también la evolución de su definición:

> **1780**. s. f. La edad de catorce años en el varon, y de doce en la muger. *Pubertas*.
>
> **1817**. s. f. La aptitud para reproducirse, que en el varon se supone a la edad de catorce años, y en la muger á los doce. Pubertas.
>
> **1884** y **1925**. f. Época de la vida en que empieza á manifestarse la aptitud para la reproducción.
>
> **1992** y **2001**. f. Primera fase de la adolescencia en la cual se producen las modificaciones propias del paso de la infancia a la edad adulta.

Vaya, que parece que actualmente se considera *pubertad* como una primera fase de la *adolescencia*, de duración indefinida pero seguramente de algunos años, mientras que antes (1780) era algo así como un punto exacto (14 años en hombres, 12 en mujeres), un hito en el cual se entraba en la adolescencia.

Centrémonos en lo estrictamente lingüístico: ¿A qué se debe esta evolución en la denominación? ¿Por qué se fijaba exactamente el rango 14 a 25 años para la adolescencia? ¿Acaso no es extraño que el diccionario tomara esta definición en una época donde la [esperanza de vida era bastante baja](https://politikon.es/2015/06/05/cuanto-mas-vivimos-hoy-la-revolucion-de-la-salud/), con lo que podemos suponer además que bastante gente ya tenía hijos al llegar a los 25 años?

Comment: creo que esto es mas una pregunta de psicologia y biologia sobre un termino científico  que del español

Comment: @Mike me interesa conocer qué evolución ha hecho que la lengua haya ido variando su significado progresivamente

Comment: A través del CORDE encuentro: "...como cuando los omnes comiençan en la su tercera edad, a la que dizen **adolescencia**, e esto es de **quinze años adelante** ..." Alfonso X - General Estoria. Primera parte c. 1275.

Comment: Creo que el término es equiparable a "juventud" [ver el Diccionario de Corominas], y que simplemente se han modificado los límites de las edades que lo marcan, cuestión que, como indica Mike, es más una cuestión de pisología y biología que del idioma en si.

Answer (score 1):

Una pista que encuentro para la actual extensión de la adolescencia como etapa en la vida es el nacimiento de las muelas de juicio, que salen entre los 17 y los 25 años [1](https://www.mayoclinic.org/es-es/diseases-conditions/wisdom-teeth/symptoms-causes/syc-20373808).

Alguien que no tiene dichas muelas *adolece* de ellas.

Sin embargo, según el artículo [*Etimología de la palabra adolescencia*](http://www.alternativateatral.com/tema17274-etimologia-de-la-palabra-adolescencia) antiguamente la adolescencia representaba algo muy distinto de una carencia:

> Entre los romanos la *adolescentia* no era una edad donde se "adolecía de algo" o se sufriera.
>
> En latín la palabra *adolescentia*, proviene del verbo *adolesco*, que no deriva de *ad* y *doleo*, sino de *ad* y *oleo* y su incoativo *olesco*. Este verbo expresa la idea de "el crepitar de los fuegos sagrados; los que llevan y transmiten el fuego; el crecer, desarrollarse, desenvolverse la razón, el ardor".

La definición antigua es más adecuada a esa realidad de vidas tan cortas.

Comment: Interesante respuesta Mariana, ¡gracias!